# Retrieve data from action in same controller created via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm missing something very simple, just not sure what. I have two actions in the same controller `AppProxy`. One action, `AppProxy#return_credit` is used to `POST` data too via AJAX, and it works great:

```
def return_credit
  customer = Customer.find_by(email: params["email"])
  @credit_amount = customer.credit_amount.to_f
  render json: @credit_amount, :status => :ok
end
```

The above action works great, and returns `@credit_amount` just fine. However, when I need to use `@credit_amount` in another action within the same controller, `AppProxy#credit` that feeds a view, `@credit_amount` has disappeared and is now empty.

```
def credit
  @credit_amount
  # if I do puts "#{@credit_amount}" here its empty, 
  # and obviously same in view
end
```

I've also tried putting `attr_reader :credit_amount` in this controller, but it doesn't help.

How can I use the `@credit_amount` variable in my `credit` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `credit` action located in the different controller, you can not share variables between two controllers in such manner. For this purpose, there is `Model`.

**Update:**

You have updated question, and answer the same, you can not share variables between two actions(*requests*) in such manner. You can move logic to separate method

```
def set_credit_amount
  customer = Customer.find_by(email: params["email"])
  @credit_amount = customer.credit_amount.to_f
end
```

and use this method in `before_action` or call directly in actions, however, you can not save the variable(`data`) in one action(*request*) and then use it in another.

If you want to share data between two actions(*requests*), you need to store it somewhere., in `sessions` or in NoSQL Database like Redis.

Comment: hmm, I need to save it or find it again.. maybe I can use redis instead..

Answer (score 0):

@credit_amount needs to be set again.

If you were to use this again:

```
customer = Customer.find_by(email: params["email"])
@credit_amount = customer.credit_amount.to_f
```

Then @credit_amount would have the same value as in #return_credit. If this is the value you would want then I would recommend making a private method which all of your actions can access.